# Keep going out of bounds ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a program I have to do in my comp sci class that is about keep track of cookie orders (think girl scout cookies).  Here is a method designed to remove a certain variety of cookie and return the number of boxes removed.  It keeps going out of bounds.  The ArrayList is the "orders" variable it is made up of CookieOrder object(CookieOrder class below)

```
public int removeVariety(String cookieVar)
{
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = orders.size() - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if(orders.get(i).getVariety().equals(cookieVar))
        {
            counter += orders.get(i).getNumBoxes();
            orders.remove(i);
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Here's the CookieOrder class

```
private String variety;
private int boxes;

public CookieOrder (String variety, int numBoxes)
{
    this.variety = variety;
    boxes = numBoxes;
}

public String getVariety()
{
    return variety;
}

public int getNumBoxes()
{
    return boxes;   
}
```

Comment: What line is the exception on?

Comment: do you know where it is out of bounds, in the outside loop or the inside loop? you could do a print statement including i in each, which should tell you where the array is getting the out of bounds exception.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `for` loop, use an iterator and use the `Iterator#remove()`

Answer (score 1):

You initialize the `for` loop variable to start from `orders.size()` and go down to `0`. But inside the loop you remove orders, so `orders.size()` is decreased but the loop variable `i` will not notice it.

The simplest solution is to loop from `0` to `orders.size() - 1` - it will be evaluated every time, so it will notice the removal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead note you should really use an [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) but I think you will not have covered that yet in your course. *Specifically note the difference between `i > 0` and `i >= 0`*:

```
public int removeVariety(String cookieVar)
{
  int counter = 0;
  for (int i = orders.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    CookieOrder o = orders.get(i);
    if (o.getVariety().equals(cookieVar))
    {
      counter += o.getNumBoxes();
      orders.remove(i);
    }
  }
  return counter;
}
```

What you are doing is basically traversing the list in reverse order, so that the removed elements do not affect the indices of the remaining elements.

**Alternative iterator based solution**

If your curious here is a solution that uses an iterator:

```
public int removeVariety(String cookieVar)
{
  int counter = 0;
  Iterator iter = orders.iterator();

  while (iter.hasNext())
  {
    CookieOrder o = iter.next();
    if (o.getVariety().equals(cookieVar))
    {
      counter += o.getNumBoxes();
      iter.remove();
    }
  }
  return counter;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  You understood me perfectly.  This iterator stuff is beyond me as this is my first year of comp sci and I'm still struggling with out of bounds exceptions.  Thank you for both bits of code and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are modifying the list as you are looping through it at the same time. That's not going to work. If you just want to sum up some value, you don't need to remove the item from the list.

Hope this helps

Comment: No sorry.  The method does have to remove the order from the list.  That is part of my assignment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8:

```
return orders.stream()
    .filter(ord -> ord.getVarienty().equals(cookieVar))
    .peek(orders::remove)
    .mapToInt(ord -> ord.getNumBoxes())
    .sum();
```

or using iterator (more imperative way):

```
int c = 0;
Iterator<CookieOrder> it = orders.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    CookieOrder current = it.next();
    if(current.getVarienty().equals(cookieVar)){
        it.remove();
        c += current.getNumBoxes();
    }
}
return c;
```

What you were trying to do is to bite your own tail here :)

Do not modify a collection that you are currently processing.